# How to return custom class object from a function in cpp?

Tags: c++, class, oop, member

I am a newbie in cpp, so far I have been learning to return int or double we will have signature like

```
double functionName(){
return something_double;
}
```

but now I am in a new situation I want to initialize a sensor and return the object created by it using a static method.

**read_sensor_data.cpp**

```
#include <Adafruit_ADS1015.h>
#include "read_sensor_data.h"
Adafruit_ADS1115 ads;


namespace SensorData 
{
  static Adafruit_ADS1115 read_sensor_data::initializeADC() {
    ads.setGain(GAIN_TWOTHIRDS);
    ads.begin();
    return ads;
  }

}
```

and header file:

```
// read_sensor_data.h
#ifndef READ_SENSOR_DATA_H
#define READ_SENSOR_DATA_H
#include <Adafruit_ADS1015.h>

namespace SensorData
{
  class read_sensor_data
  {
    public:
      static Adafruit_ADS1115 initializeADC();
  };
}

#endif
```

How can I return a custom object ads from `InitiazlieADC` member function ?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: @UnholySheep The return by value is suspicious given the other semantics shown

Answer (score 0):

Guessing at the intention of this, you wish the function to do two things:

- "Initialise" an object that's been declared locally within a source file at namespace scope
- Return a reference to it, so it can be used in other translation units

No problem!

Just return by reference:

```
  static Adafruit_ADS1115& initializeADC();
  //                     ^
```

Comment: ahh, so I can then access the `obj = initializeADC()` ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Yes if `obj` is also a reference. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I want value i.e. the object itself. the the `Adafruit_ADS1115` object `ads` has functions like `readADC_SingleEnded` that takes `int` and returns data from sensor connected to Adafruit_ADS1115 multiplexer. lie `ads.readADC_SingleEnded(1);`

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Yep, so you want a reference to the one existing `Adafruit_ADS1115` object. A chain of references will give you that. At the moment your `initialiaseADC` function returns a copy of it.

Comment: what do you mean by chain off references?

Comment: Can you please show an example ? Did you mean to do `static Adafruit_ADS1115& initializeADC();` in header file or cpp file ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Put `&` in both. Refer to the chapter in your book about references for more info :)